How do I format my Math Homework better?
I'm new to Latex and have recently started typing out my Math HW in latex. However, I feel like the homework looks "ugly", and was wondering if there are any general tips on how to improve my work?
Also, I've included the code for my current homework. I'd appreciate if I could get some feedback on it too.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Libraries.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% Shortcuts.
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\al}[1]{\begin{align}#1 \end{align}}

% Attr.
\title{Assignment}
\author{Name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    % Declaration 

\vfill
    \textit{We wish to acknowledge this land on which the University of Toronto operates. For thousands of years it has been the traditional land of the Huron-Wendat, the Seneca, and the Mississaugas of the Credit. Today, this meeting place is still the home to many Indigenous people from across Turtle Island.} 

    \textit{We do not acknowledge the land in hope of justifying settler colonialism or understate the traumatic horror it has brought to the land. Instead, we recognize that the claim of institutions or persons “owning” the land as “private property” is fallacious, and that we are privileged to have the opportunity to work on this land.} 

    \textit{In our work, we strive not only for advancements in our fields of expertise but also for diversity, equity, inclusion, and evolving human rights that we are trying to better understand every day. It is through these efforts that we could have some hope of honoring the land and all that it represents.}

\vfill % Add flexible vertical space after the paragraph


\newpage
\section*{Question 3}
Define $(a_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ and $(b_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ as follows: \\
Let $0<b_1<a_1$, 
$$a_{n+1}=$$
$$b_{n+1}$$
By the inequality, for all $n \in \mb{N}$,
$$a_n= \frac{a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}}{2} $$

For all $n \in \mb{N}$

$$a_n \geq a_{n+1}$$
Therefore, $(a_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ is monotonically decreasing by definition. \\ Observe that 
$$a_n = \frac{a_1+b_1}{2^{n-1}} + \sum^{n-1}_{i=2}\frac{b_i}{2^{n-i}}$$
We know $a_1, b_1 > 0$ and $b_i = \sqrt{a_{i-1}b_{i-1}} \geq 0,$ which imply $a_n >0$, so we can pick some real $m < 0$ and $\forall n\in \mb{N}, m \leq a_n$. Therefore, $(a_n)^\infty_{i=1}$ is bounded below. \textbf{By the Monotone Convergence Theorem (MCT),} $\boldsymbol{(a_n)^\infty_{i=1}}$ \textbf{converges.} 
\\ 
\\
Similarly, for all $n\in \mb{N}, a_n > b_n$,
$${b_{n+1}\geq b_n}$$
Therefore, $(b_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ is monotonically increasing. 
For all $n \in \mb{N}, b_n \leq a_n$  and $a_n \leq a_1$, it follows that $b_n \leq a_1$. Thus, $(b_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ is bounded above. \textbf{By MCT,} $\boldsymbol{(b_n)^\infty_{n=1}}$ \textbf{converges.}

\end{document}


Hi! "better" is subjective, so it would be hard to give a definitive answer. I think a good way to approach this problem would be to identify parts that aren't to your taste, and then find out why they aren't. Then you could tackle them one part at a time. For example, I was having a similar trouble with a document of mine, and I actually took a ruler to an old book so I could mimic its formatting - which was pretty straightforward, and made my document much more to my liking.  Again, the best way to tackle a problem is to have a specific, concrete objective.

Hi @Jasper, thanks for the input, that's a great point:)!
I noticed that in my work, sometimes there were unwanted space before a sentence on a new line.
(e.g., in my work, before
" For all $n \in \mb{N}" ).
How should I go about fixing this?

I'd use \noindent before the "For all" to remove the indent. By the way, I'd suggest turning off the "Try to Compile Despite Errors", because on my machine, it didn't run until I forced it too. This will allow you to catch errors in your documents before they become too pronounced. Good LaTeX formatting comes with experience, so don't be disheartened if things are difficult at first. Come here with any technical questions too; that'll help.

Better is subjective, but:

For starters, Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?
Don't have consecutive display environments.  Use gather*, align*, or multline* as appropriate.
"Unwanted space before a newline" is the indentation of a new paragraph.  If you don't want that, then don't start a new paragraph (which is caused by a blank line).  And be careful with your blank lines.  You don't want one between text and the displayed equation it introduces.
Your proposed shortcuts aren't great.  As soon as someone else looks at your file, they won't know what you mean.  (I would also guess that \al{stuff} will break weirdly, but don't know enough to be sure.)  Better would be \newcommand{\reals}{\mathbb{R}} or \newcommand{\naturals}{\mathbb{N}} because then the command name means something.
Don't use consecutive \\ just to get vertical spacing.  Use \bigskip (or \medskip or \smallskip).
Try not to use \\ just to get to the next line.  Typographically, it should either be a new paragraph, or on the previous line.


May I ask what does "consecutive display environments" mean?

A display environment is \[...\] (which had been $$...$$).  You shouldn't have more than one in a row because the alternatives end up with better spacing and semantics.
